# Reuse method reference differing in signature using functional interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following method which returns a string depending on the presence of a Language.

```
private String getInLanguage(Function<Locale, String> withLang,
                             Supplier<String> withoutLang) {
    Locale locale = getLocaleFromSomewhere();
    if (locale != null) {
        return withLang.apply(locale);
    } else {
        return withoutLang.get();
    }
}
```

I then call it like this:

```
private String getMyObjectName(MyObject obj) {
    return getInLanguage(obj::getName, obj::getName);
}

private String getExternalObjectDescription(ExternalObject obj) {
    return getInLanguage(obj::getDescription, obj::getDescription);
}
```

Where `MyObject` has the methods `String getName()` and `String getName(Locale loc)`.

The method reference in the code looks the same for both arguments. So for purely **esthetical** reasons it would be nice if it was possible to just write

```
return getInLanguage(obj::getName);
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You should take a look at [method overloading](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/).

Comment: The method-references are **not** the same because they refer to 2 different methods. They _can_ be written in the source code in the same way in this particular circonstance, but they have 2 very different meaning after compilation. In short, this is not code duplication.

Comment: @Jezor and this is related how? The question is about syntactic sugar, the methods are already overloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods `String getName()` and `String getName(Locale loc)` are different methods and the fact, that they have the same name, is irrelevant to the way they work and it can not be exploited in any way.

By giving them the same name, you only document a semantic relationship. So if you want to avoid specifying method references to the same semantic operation, you have to solve it on the semantic level. The parameter-less `getName` method quite likely performs the same operation with a fall-back, which could be provided to the other `getName` method in the first place:

```
private String getInLanguage(Function<Locale, String> withLang,
                             Supplier<Locale> defaultSupplier) {
    Locale locale=getLocaleFromSomewhere();
    return withLang.apply(locale == null? defaultSupplier.get(): locale);
}
```

Fallback to use the default locale:

```
private String getString1(MyObject obj) {
    return getInLanguage(obj::getName, Locale::getDefault);
}
```

Fallback to denote a locale-insensitive operation:

```
private String getString1(MyObject obj) {
    return getInLanguage(obj::getName, ()->Locale.ROOT);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a neater solution is to just implement it in one method. Use an Optional to execute your method references and avoid the messy syntax of passing the functional interfaces.

```
private String getString1(MyObject obj) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(getLocaleFromSomewhere())
        .map(obj::getName)
        .orElseGet(obj::getName);
}
```

Comment: Actually this was just an example, there are much more methods like `getString1()`, and they all share the functionality I factored out in `getInLanguage()`. However, I like you solution to implement `getInLanguage()`

Answer (score 1):

You state that `The method reference in the code is the same for both arguments` but it is not true.
They points to different method. So there is no good solution for you.